# Nuxt How to make Initialization loading splash screen

Tags: nuxt.js, loading, splash-screen

I’m New to Nuxt, I tried to find how to make splash loading screen question, but I always found the questions only talk about iOS splash screen.

Did anyone know the way to make splash screen when the site content are Initialization and content full loaded (or if there’re any feature, function can do it?), like awwwards’s most site’s splash screen:

https://www.woset.world/

https://garden-eight.com/

They made the initialization splash screen also with Nuxt. but I can’t figure it out how to make splash screen like that?

(I think maybe it’s relative with Nuxt PWA or Service Worker?)

Comment: What if you create a full screen div(or component) inside your default.vue and then hide it when the page is fully loaded?

Comment: How would you determine "fully loaded"? Can this be done generically in nuxt? Or would it be up to my implementation...